# Submitting Open Graph actions that require two Facebook users

Tags: facebook, submit, action, facebook-opengraph

We are working on a website which has two types of user: TypeA and TypeB and there are some Open Graph actions that we want to submit. To be able to test them correctly, one user of each type has to be created through Facebook Login, since the actions are the result of some interactions between Facebook users of the website.

However, we have not found much information about Open Graph actions that involve the interaction between users. Most of the info out there refers to actions generated when the user interacts with the app/website itself.

It seems to us that Facebook uses the "Open Graph Test User" to test the submitted actions, but as I have explained, one user will not be enough to test our actions.

So my questions would be:

- Are we right in our assumption about the "Open Graph Test User"?
- Is it possible to submit this type of Open Graph actions?
- If so, what should we do to submit them?
- Is there anything we have to do so that Facebook is able to test our actions?

Comment: Additionally to what Vijay said, you can now upload screenshots directly in the submission process (as announced in the developer blog about a week ago, https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/11/14/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) – this could be another way of showing the review team more clearly what exactly is happening when publishing your OG action.

Answer (score 2):

I think as per [Understanding the Open Graph Approval Submission Process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/submission-process/) , each action item in the Open graph has the provision to give the steps to reproduce the action while we submit.

Here we can explain the steps in detail and the testing environment can be a live/staging.

As you told there are two types of user, you can explain in detail how to change the user type or register as either user type and then they can test.

As you are aware using the Application settings we can create as many test users as we can and we can friend them in FB also. I guess FB also will do the same to test the interaction b/w users. The key point is you have explain in detail about how to test while submitting.